# Change Size Textarea onCheck

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to change the size of the textarea onClick on the checkbox

When it's unchecked the Textarea will have 8 Rows,

When it's checked the Textarea will have 7 rows + **1 textfield under it.**

Is there a way to do it ?

[image]

HTML

```
   <textarea *ngIf="mode === 1" id="message" rows="8" (ngModelChange)="updateV($event)" [ngModel]="message" value="MessageFinal"
        </textarea>
```

My ToggleItem ( check )

```
  <ion-toggle class="toggle-small" toggle-class="toggle-calm"   (ionChange)="AddChild(ioToggle.checked)"  #ioToggle ></ion-toggle>
```

AddChild_function.ts

```
addChild(state) {
    const messageTextarea = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('message'));
    console.log(this.rows) // will give me how much i have when i check or uncheck
    console.log(messageTextarea)

    if (state === true) {
      this.messageTextarea.rows=7
      console.log(messageTextarea)

    } else if (state === false) {
this.messageTextarea.rows=8
    }
```

Comment: This is very basic manipulation. Of course there's a way to do this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Please post a minimal HTML, CSS, and JS needed to reproduce your problemset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the checkbox an onclick even and an ID, give the textarea an ID and use `document.getElementById()` function to manipulate the elements properties.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
</head>

<body>

<input id="check1" type="checkbox" onclick="resizeTextarea()" />
<textarea id="textArea" rows="7" col="50" ></textarea>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function resizeTextarea(){
        var checked = document.getElementById("check1").checked;

        if(checked)
             document.getElementById('textArea').rows = "8";      
        else
            document.getElementById('textArea').rows = "7";  
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got the error, ;The property 'rows' does not exist on value of type 'HTMLElement'

Comment: can you show me the code and the error message?

Comment: your using typescript, try something like `var inputValue = (<HTMLTextAreaElement>document.getElementById('textArea')).rows;`

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: Found it, thank you .. i did .rows); instead of ).rows

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.

Comment: Sorry  sir did the change but the textarea still the same :/

Comment: I did this  let message = (<HTMLTextAreaElement>document.getElementById('message')).rows;
 if (state === true) {
      let message=5;
      console.log(messageTextarea)


      newMessage = newMessage.substring(selecStart, 0) + newMessage.substring(selectEnd, newMessage.length) + '\n' + this.user.firstname;

    } else if (state === false) {
      let message=2;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169890/discussion-between-thatguy-and-taieb).